# how to get a new line with php fprintf()

Tags: php, printf

I need each line of data to print on the next line. How do you do a line break with fprintf()???

```
echo fprintf($handle, "%-22s %-30s %-30s %-17s %-2s %-9s %-10s",$record_type,$name,$address,$city,$state,$postal,$phone);
```

Comment: The constant `PHP_EOL` will evaluate to the newline character(s) for your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\n` to add a line break inside `fprintf`. Here's the full documentation on the fuction: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fprintf.php

You can see more about the formatting inside the `sprintf` documentation: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Here's an example using your code (not sure exactly what you're trying to do with line breaks):

```
echo fprintf($handle, "%-22s\n%-30s\n", $record_type, $name);
```

Comment: no it's not the fprints they are correct and ready to go and work fine. I need a while loop or something so the customer fprintf prints and then all the invoice detail for that customer fprintf prints and then the summary for those invoices for that customer fprintf prints then it goes to the next customer so on and so on until it runs out of customers